# Can't extend C drive on my Windows 10 Pro

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, disk-space

I've searched tutorial "how to extend C partition on Windows 10" on Google. Also i've tried some of those as well. But i still can't find out how to solve this issue. Can anyone help me to point out what the problem is ?

[image]

Comment: The problem is that your C drive is sandwiched between two other partitions right now. You can only extend a volume in Disk Management if there is unallocated space on either side of it.

Comment: use a 3rd party partitioning tool to move the last partition to make room for the C drive

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To resize this safely, you'll need a 3rd party partition tool. You can try EaseUS, which I think is still free and I have used it before successfully: http://www.partition-tool.com/personal.htm

However, the 510MB recovery partition may be useless and may be able to just be deleted.

It really depends on the operating system and configuration. If we look at your existing partition layout we see a pretty normal looking 450MB recovery partition followed by a 100MB EFI System disk, and then the primary C: drive. This is likely a standard windows 10 deployment. The 450MB partition is the Windows Recovery Environment, the EFI System disk holds the boot files.

The question is, what is the 510MB partition for? It's possible this could be for BitLocker and contain BitLocker system files. In this case you definitely should not delete this partition. However, if we look at the image you provided of disk management, none of the partitions are labeled as being Bitlocker Encrypted.

We also know that the 510MB partition isn't big enough to be an OEM recovery image. So, personally, I would take a closer look at that partition and see if I could determine what is on it. You can do that, usually, by assigning a drive letter to it temporarily and browsing the contents. If you don't understand what you see, you can probably post here with a few images of the contents and we can help you further.

However, I am fairly confident this 510MB partition will have no impact on the system if it is removed. But, removing it is definitely done at your own risk. The benefit is that if you remove it, you can easily expand your C: drive to use the rest of the free space. The drawback is that this could be some kind of important partition I have overlooked and your system won't boot anymore.

If you choose to delete it, you can try to do so from within disk management. But, usually the operating system will prevent you from deleting this type of partition.

Instead, you can delete it from the command prompt.

Start command prompt and use the following commands:

```
diskpart
list disk
select disk x
list partition
select partition y
delete partition override
```

Replace `x` with the number of the disk and `y` with the number of the partition, both are listed during the `list` commands above. Make sure you are deleting the right partition. Typing in the wrong thing here will be unforgiving.

Deleting the 510MB recovery partition and expanding the C: drive is the quickest, most straight forward way. But, it comes with some risk. Using a 3rd party tool would be the safest, but will take more work.

Good luck, let us know what you come up with!

Comment: ok, i will try it later

Comment: "The 510MB recovery partition is useless." This is completely and factually incorrect. The windows recovery partition contains a recovery environment accessible during startup that can be used to repair a damaged windows installation. Most OEMs also place the factory restore feature on this partition so that, in the worst case scenario (software wise), you can return to a functioning, factory Windows installation. There is no reason one can't delete the recovery partition but misinforming people that it's useless robs people of the chance to make that decision for themselves.

Comment: Well said, but the partitions are too small to be an OEM factory image. There are also multiple recovery partitions on this hard drive. The Windows 10 recovery environment should be on the 450MB partition. It's true the 510MB might be the windows recovery environment, we really don't know for sure, but even if it was missing it would still be a simple matter to recovery the system with a bootable USB and the Media Creation Tool. With the trouble it is causing, the simplest thing to do is get rid of it. It won't be missed.

Comment: Two thoughts: (1) I'd recommend amending your answer to indicate why you think the 510MB partition is useless (which, in this case, is probably because there is a 450MB one at the beginning of the drive) and advising someone to check before they delete it. (2) I'd recommend changing `x` in your example to `y` for the partition - otherwise it looks like you type in the disk number in when you're trying to delete the partition.

Comment: Thanks, I have taken all your comments in to consideration and revised my post.

Comment: I tried that software and it did not solve my problem, so what i did is to delete my newly created D part in order to change its state to unallocated so that I can extend my C drive.